# Jasmine SpyOn haveBeenCalled on function reference don't work (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

In my Angular controller I have implemented a listener, that call a function by reference:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', vm.popoverChooseProfile.remove);
```

I have implemented a test with Karma and Jasmine.

```
  it('should remove the popover the scope is destroy', function() {
    var vm = createController();

    vm.popoverChooseProfile = MOCK_POPOVER;

    spyOn(vm.popoverChooseProfile, 'remove');

    $scope.$destroy();
    expect(vm.popoverChooseProfile.remove).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The test above fail but if I wrap the vm.popoverChooseProfile.remove reference in an anonymous function the test succeed

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {

vm.popoverChooseProfile.remove();

});
```

To my mind the anonymous function is useless in this case. Have you got an idea how to make the spy works with reference function ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign handler to the event, you give it the link to the function and not to the property of the object. It is same as to write:

```
var handler = vm.popoverChooseProfile.remove;
$scope.$on('$destroy', handler);
```

Jasmine, to check if the function has been called, replaces the original property to its own function, that saves the status if it was called, and calles the original function if needed.

So at the time the event occures, the vm.popoverChooseProfile.remove !== handler, so the test fails.

To fix it you should either do wrapping as you did, or set spyOn before you set the event listener.